# Unconditioned conditioned expectation

Tags: probability

I am looking at the following problem in the perspective of finance and filtration. However, the problem does not pertain to just that. I know this is really silly, and I am missing something very obvious.

Suppose I have a conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X_0]$$

I need to see why, if I multiply the above by $P(X_0)$ - probability of $X_0$, I would get back the unconditioned expectation of $X$.
I know that:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

and that

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^X}x f(x) dx$$

But I cannot write out the $\mathbb{E}[X|X_0]$ in the integral form... I just do not remember how to...

EDIT: Oh, would it be something of the form: $\int_{-\infty}^{X_0} x f(x) dx$ ?  So I guess the question is why: $\int_{-\infty}^{X_0}x f(x) dx \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{X_0}f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^X}xf(x) dx$... Does not look right to me

Comment: The actual result is that $$E(E(X\mid X_0))=E(X)$$ that is, introducing any function $g$ such that $$E(X\mid X_0)=g(X_0)$$ and the PDF $f_0$ of $X_0$, one has $$\int_\mathbb R g(z)f_0(z)\,dz=E(X)$$

Comment: Correct. Thanks

Comment: Thus... question solved?

Comment: Indeed. It is solved. If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Did Actually... How is $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(z) f_{0}(z) dz = \mathbb{E}[X]}$ ?

Comment: Well, because the LHS is by definition $E(g(X_0))=E(E(X\mid X_0))=E(X)$.

Comment: So this is just a definition and no proofs are required? I have figured out that this is called a law of total expectation and wikipedia has proofs for the discrete and continuous cases. What I am interested in, is the discrete case, however, they use measure theory there, which I am not familiar with yet, unfortunately

Comment: If you are interested in the finite case, i.e. where $X_0$ takes values in say $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then you could use that

$\mathbb{E}[X \, |\, X_0] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{i\}}(X_0) \mathbb{E}[X \, |\, X_0 = i]$.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \, | \, X_0]] = \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_0 = k) \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{i\}}(k) \mathbb{E}[X \, |\, X_0 = i] = \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_0 = k) \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, X_0 = k] = E[X]$. The last line is from the partition theorem, which is weaker than the previous used law of iterated expectation. But in general: You need measure theory to show this when $X$ is continuous.

Comment: @Furrer I know some Analysis so I may be able to understand the continuous proof if I were pointed to the areas of measure theory that I have to look up